# Convertion parameter numeric month to title month

Tags: jasper-reports

I have month parameter in *JasperReports* report which will be changed into title of month. I didn't use any query to change them. I try this code:

```
$P{MONTH}.intValue()==1?"JAN":
    $P{MONTH}.intValue()==2?"FEB":
        $P{MONTH}.intValue()==3?"MAR":
            $P{MONTH}.intValue()==4?"APR":
                $P{MONTH}.intValue()==5?"MAY":
                    $P{MONTH}.intValue()==6?"JUN":
                        $P{MONTH}.intValue()==7?"JUL":
                            $P{MONTH}.intValue()==8?"AUG":
                                $P{MONTH}.intValue()==9?"SEP":
                                    $P{MONTH}.intValue()==10?"OCT":
                                        $P{MONTH}.intValue()==11?"NOV":"DEC";
```

but it didn't work. Could anyone know the solution for me?

Comment: Is this month parameter '$F{MONTH}' representing a complete date? Or it is just a int/String containing a value from 1 to 12?

Comment: it's just int which filled by 1-12. Fyi, i use parameter, so it uses $P{MONTH}. So, do you have any idea for me? Thanks Endrik

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
$F{MONTH}.intValue()==1?"JAN":
    $F{MONTH}.intValue()==2?"FEB":
        $F{MONTH}.intValue()==3?"MAR":
            $F{MONTH}.intValue()==4?"APR":
                $F{MONTH}.intValue()==5?"MAY":
                    $F{MONTH}.intValue()==6?"JUN":
                        $F{MONTH}.intValue()==7?"JUL":
                            $F{MONTH}.intValue()==8?"AUG":
                                $F{MONTH}.intValue()==9?"SEP":
                                    $F{MONTH}.intValue()==10?"OCT":
                                        $F{MONTH}.intValue()==11?"NOV":"DEC"
```

It may be the semi-colon at the end that's the problem

It may also be that you are using a Parameter - .intValue() doesn't seem valid for a Parameter

Comment: Thanks Adam, but just like I've mentioned above, i use Parameter not Field in order to define month's title. Do you have other suggestion? Thanks in advanced